# Issue regarding Unicode in pdf

Tags: pdf, unicode

I have written a code, which generates simple pdf documents. But i couldn't able to render unicode characters into pdf. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you provide some more specific information. How can we tell what you do wrong if you merely say you *have written a code, which generates simple pdf documents*? All there is to say is that you did it wrong.

Comment: Which library are you using to create PDF (iText or some other tool)? Which programming language are you using (Java, C#,...)? It is hard to believe that you'd expect a specific answer to such an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have the following `String`s in Unicode:

```
public static final String CZECH =
        "Podivn\u00fd p\u0159\u00edpad Dr. Jekylla a pana Hyda";
public static final String RUSSIAN =
        "\u0421\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f "
        + "\u0438\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f "
        + "\u0434\u043e\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0430 "
        + "\u0414\u0436\u0435\u043a\u0438\u043b\u0430 \u0438 "
        + "\u043c\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430 "
        + "\u0425\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0430";
public static final String KOREAN =
        "\ud558\uc774\ub4dc, \uc9c0\ud0ac, \ub098";
```

Then you need to find font programs that are able to render those characters. For instance:

```
public static final String FONT = "src/main/resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
public static final String HCRBATANG = "src/main/resources/fonts/HANBatang.ttf";
```

FreeSans is a free font usually shipped with Linux; it supports a lot of languages, but not all. For instance: Korean isn't supported, hence we also use HAN Batang.

We use these font programs to create `PdfFont` objects, and we use those objects in `Paragraph` objects:

```
PdfFont freeUnicode =
    PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
document.add(new Paragraph().setFont(freeUnicode)
    .add(CZECH).add(" by Robert Louis Stevenson"));
document.add(new Paragraph().setFont(freeUnicode)
    .add(RUSSIAN).add(" by Robert Louis Stevenson"));
PdfFont fontUnicode =
    PdfFontFactory.createFont(HCRBATANG, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
document.add(new Paragraph().setFont(fontUnicode)
    .add(KOREAN).add(" by Robert Louis Stevenson"));
```

The result is shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

As you can see, rendering Unicode is very simple when using iText 7. This example is taken from [chapter 1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-pdffont-class) of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial.

If this is not the information you were looking for, fix your question and explain which tool you used instead of iText, and which programming language.